# How to find the probability of declaring faulty

Tags: probability

My question:

Consider a company that assembles computers. The probability of a faulty assembly of any computer is $x$. The company therefore subjects each computer to a testing process. This testing process gives the correct result for any computer with a probability of $y$. what is the probability of a computer being declared faulty?

I am a $12$ grade student. Kindly help me solve dis hard problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Try to think about the two different cases: 1. The probability of picking a faulty computer and then correctly finding it to be faulty. 2. The probability of picking a functional computer and then incorrectly finding it to be faulty. Once you have these two you just have to add them together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the event $D$ as "Declared faulty" and the event $F$ as that a computer is faulty. By law of total probability

$$
P(D) = P(D\mid F)P(F) + P(D \mid F^c)P(F^c)
$$
We know that they give the correct answer with probability $y$ so $P(D \mid F)=y$ and $P(D\mid F^c)=1-y$. Also we know $P(F)=x$ and $P(F^c)=1-x$ so it remains to put everything together.